# Removing Tabs using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to create an Activity to give the user the option to add and remove certain tabs based on an option selected by the user using a toggle button. So if I have 4 tabs I need 4 toggle buttons that hide or add each of those tabs. The tabs are shown using ViewPager and I use FragmentPagerAdpater to show the different Fragments for each tab on the screen. What would I need to do in order to show and hide these same 4 tabs? From my research so far I see that calling destroyItem and instantiateItem but i'm not sure how to use these. I have posted code below. Any advice or helpful links will be appreciated.

```
class TabPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {


    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_MAIN:
                if (mMainFragment == null) {
                    mMainFragment = JudgeMainFragment.newInstance();
                }
                return mMainFragment;
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_VERDICTS:
                if (mVerdictFragment == null) {
                    mVerdictFragment = JudgeVerdictFragment.newInstance();
                }
                return mVerdictFragment;
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_CLASSIFY:
                if (mClassifyFragment == null) {
                    mClassifyFragment = JudgeClassifyFragment.newInstance();
                }
                return mClassifyFragment;
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_SIDEBAR:
                if (mSidebarFragment == null) {
                    mSidebarFragment = JudgeSidebarFragment.newInstance((SidebarCall) mActivity);
                }
                return mSidebarFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = (JudgeActivity) getActivity();
    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(mActivity, R.style.Theme_JudgePageIndicatorDefaults);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_judge, container, false);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new TabPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    return mView;
}
```

Comment: have you tried changing pager adapter contents and notifying tabView or host?

Comment: Changing information like buttons and sliders in each Fragment in the ViewPager works fine if that's what you mean by changing pager adapter contents. And there is no tab view it's just a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdpater set to it.