# Calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to update a view pager using FragmentPagerAdapter. Every time I call notifyDataSetChanged from my adapter I get a force close with this error `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions".`

Any pointers on this would be helpful I have posted code below and I will post 2 links to 2 other questions I have had on this topic after this. Updating this ViewPager has been giving me a serious headache so any advice would be appreciated.

[Removing Tabs using FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776240/removing-tabs-using-fragmentpageradapter) , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834861/adding-and-removing-tabs-using-fragmentpageradapter

```
public void setTabsToSHow() {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(listOfTitles.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}






class TabPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_MAIN:
                if (mMainFragment == null) {
                    mMainFragment = JudgeMainFragment.newInstance();
                }
                return mMainFragment;
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_VERDICTS:
                if (mVerdictFragment == null) {
                    mVerdictFragment = JudgeVerdictFragment.newInstance();
                }
                return mVerdictFragment;
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_CLASSIFY:
                if (mClassifyFragment == null) {
                    mClassifyFragment = JudgeClassifyFragment.newInstance();
                }
                return mClassifyFragment;
            case JudgeActivity.JUDGE_SIDEBAR:
                if (mSidebarFragment == null) {
                    mSidebarFragment = JudgeSidebarFragment.newInstance((SidebarCall) mActivity);
                }
                return mSidebarFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listOfTitles.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "itempostioton",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return POSITION_NONE ;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    //  return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase(Locale.US);

        //Notify data set changed can only be called from inside this class
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return listOfTitles.get(position);
    }








}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `notifyDataSetChanged();` from `public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` method

Secondly, do not return from `case` statements, rather do assignment to local variable and finally return the fragment. Use `break` after every case block.